# JavaServer faces: partials in templates

Tags: jsf

I have just taken a look at JavaServer Faces especially PrimeFaces.

What i am currently missing is something like partials in Ruby on Rails so that i do not have to repeat everything in every template.So just something simple like:

```
<%= render :partial => 'common/menu' %>
```

Maybe this is a simple question but i have found nothing about it in the web. Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Ruby on Rails but probably what you are looking for is [facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html).

It can be used both to create templates with the basic structure of your page and to group multiple elements into a composite which then can be reused.

Comment: Thanks, after i knew i had to search for composition i stumbled upon this link  [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/) and at the bottom there is the answer under "A Templating Example".